# How can I print a new line in a toString() method in java

Tags: java, eclipse-luna

Instead of the many `system.out.println()` lines, I want to write `System.out.println(b)` in TestBook.java file.
So what should I write in the `toString()` in the Book class to return the same results to look like below

```
//Title: xxx
//Author:xxx
//Years:xxx
//Pages:xxx
//edition: xxxx
//==================================

public class Book {

String title;
String author;
int yearOfPublishing;
int numberOfPages;
int eddition;

Book ()
{}

Book ( String title, String author, int yop, int nop, int eddition)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    yearOfPublishing = yop;
    numberOfPages = nop;
    this.eddition = eddition;

}

public String toString()
    {
    // return what?? how can i return new lines
    }
}

public class TestBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Book b = new Book("Data", "Joe", 2015, 276, 3);

        System.out.println ( "Title : " +b.title);
        System.out.println ( "Author : " +b.author);
        System.out.println ( "Year : " +b.yearOfPublishing);
        System.out.println ( "Pages : " +b.numberOfPages);
        System.out.println ( "Eddition : " +b.eddition);    
        System.out.println ("==================================");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the output will always be always consumed on *nix, Windows or Mac prior to OS X, you can respectively use `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r`
- If you want the code to be platform independent and you will consume the data on the same platform on which it is produced, you can use `String.format("%n")`, `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or `System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 3):

For others that happen across this question while possibly trying to do what I had been doing in the past using Eclipse's Source menu item Generate toString()... with a template.  I used to try this as the template:

`${object.className} [\n${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}]`

However that resulted in the following for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NEDCustomer [\\nsubscriberType=" + subscriberType + "]";
```

**Note:** the "\n" was replaced with "\n" which obviously didnt work in the output console or log so then I'd do a quick search and replace to replace the double backslash with a single.

With a new eclipse workspace up and going, I finally decided to do a quick google once again and find out if there was a better way to do it in which case I found this SO question, however prior to finding it I noticed an eclipse.org link of [tostring templates](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-tostring-templates.htm) so I went back to that web page after this questions answers were off topic for me and it was as simple as editing the template to instead be:

```
${object.className} [
    ${member.name()}=${member.value}, 
    ${otherMembers}]
```

And eclipse now properly generates the following (I did end up adding a tab for clarity/formatting):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NEDCustomer [\n\tsubscriberType=" + subscriberType + "]";
```

And again, this doesnt totally answer the OP's question as they were manually creating the toString method however in a way it does or enhances it by using Eclipse's toString template which can save considerable time especially if you have 20+ variables.

Hope this possibly helps others

Comment: This guy get's it. Thanks for the great answer, saves me so much time when generating `.toString()` for beans :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just return newline characters inline with the data you want to format:

```
return "Title : " + title + "\nAuthor : " + author ...
```

Note that this may or may not be the best approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the shortest answer I have ever given.

Google This:

```
\n
```